# How do you visually identify aircraft from the ground?

Tags: plane-spotting, aircraft-identification

Are there any good resources that teach you how to identify jetliners from the ground? I'd love to see some great comparative photos of their silhouettes. Books or websites are both ok.

For example, here's a plane that was flying over yesterday en-route to KSFO. I'm guessing it's a 747 or A380, but I can't easily guess from this angle.

[image: silhouette of plane from the ground]

Comment: given the tail and what has been said [here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/how-can-i-tell-apart-an-airbus-from-a-boeing) I would say that's a 747

Comment: not just the tail, the shape of the wing, the diameter of the engines, all indicate a 747 and an early model at that.

Answer (score 10):

The canonical reference for aircraft recognition would be [*Jane's All the World's Aircraft*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane's_All_the_World's_Aircraft).

http://www.airliners.net is also a useful resource, but generally means working from photos - the line drawings in *Jane's* are often easier to use because they abstract away things like airline liveries and distill the aircraft down to its basic shapes.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Looks like IHS is "restructuring" (breaking every link on) their website. Moved the link to Wikipedia for now.

Answer (score 5):

[A Field Guide to Airplanes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0618411275) is also really good. I find it better than [Jane's Aircraft Recognition Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0061346195) because it is categorized by aircraft appearance, and also is written like a field guide as opposed to a reference book.