# Would a large airliner such as a 747 or an A380 survive an inversion?

Tags: airliner

Could any large airliner or GA aircraft survive a horizontal roll? Or would a large aircraft break up from structural damage?

Comment: not properly an horizontal roll, but pretty close: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/149/2698

Answer (score 10):

Could it? Yes.
[Tex Johnson famously performed a roll in a Boeing 707.](http://youtu.be/Ra_khhzuFlE) If performed properly it is a 1G maneuver (the airframe experiences +1G stresses through the maneuver - as far as it's concerned nothing unusual is happening).

Should you attempt such a maneuver without aerobatic training? **No.**
Should you attempt it in an aircraft not certificated for aerobatic flight? **Absolutely Not.**
This is one of those "If you do it wrong the wings fall off" maneuvers, and chances are you're not Tex Johnson.

Comment: Also should be noted that A380 won't let you do it as it has both pitch and roll angle limit. B777 and 787 won't let you do it either, though I don't think they ported the system to 747-8.

Comment: I think the question is not asking about an intentional roll, but a survivable recovery from a inadvertent inverted attitude.

Answer (score 6):

A properly executed roll isn't an inversion as far as the airplane is concerned.  A ground observer will see the airplane roll and be upside down for a time, but the airplane in a 1G roll will think it is right side up the entire time.  An observer in the airplanes reference frame would not experience the roll as the gravity vector is a constant 1G pointed through the bottom of the seat during the entire roll (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMWxuKcD6vE)).

As pointed out in [this other answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/17541/65), don't do this in an airplane not certified for it.  Yes, it can be done, but if not flown perfectly the outcome is likely death in a large turbojet airplane.